# How do I simplify an overly broad if statement?

Tags: python-3.x, simplify, simplification

I have no clue how to clearly simplify the requirements for the if statement to run. 
Is there a simpler way I could have done this? 
The code is supposed to return True if the number is 2 integers near 10, either being above or below.

```
def nearten(num):
    if (abs(num - 2) % 10) == 0 or (abs(num + 2) % 10) == 0 or (abs(num - 1) % 10) == 0 or (abs(num + 1) % 10) == 0 or num % 10 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: `def nearten(num): return abs(10 - num) <= 2`

Comment: Like @PMende said: are you sure that is the condition for what you want? Because `x % 10` gets you last digits. eg `123 % 10 == 3` - which 123 is not near 10.

Comment: @foobarna I'm going off of the supplied description of the question, which is "The code is supposed to return True if the number is *2 integers near 10*, either being above or below." If Curtis's code is closer to his desired behavior than mine, I can provide modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You're certainly over-complicating things. Here is a much more flexible version:

```
def near_ten(num, close=2):
    return abs(10 - num) <= close
```

An alternate version (if you're looking for numbers close to any *multiple* of 10):

```
def near_ten_multiple(num, close=2):
    return abs(10 - (num % 10)) <= close
```